# Authenticate Youtube API on a Worker process C#

Tags: c#, process, youtube, youtube-api

I'm running a process without UI that retrieves uploaded videos from youtube. On a develpement machine it authenticates on user behalf and it works.

The problem is when process is running on a server: browser window doesn't fire for user to let use his account (it should only require to do it once).

Event viewer shows no errors whatsoever.  Service accounts doesn't seem to work with youtube, with API key is too less permissions and
oath is the only way to authenticate and get broadcasted videos. Or am I wrong?

So the question is: How to run a service as a single user and retrieve his videos without UI?

```
         private async Task Run()
                {

                    try
                    {
                        UserCredential credential;
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(StartPath + "\\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {

                            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeReadonly, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube  },
                                "user",
                                CancellationToken.None,
                                new FileDataStore("Store")
                            );
                        }

                        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                        {
                            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                            ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
                        });
    ....
                 }
```

I have also tried:

```
 String serviceAccountEmail = "e-mail";

            var certificate = new X509Certificate2(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Content/key.p12"), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

            ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
               new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
              {
                   Scopes = new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubepartnerChannelAudit, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload }
               }.FromCertificate(certificate));
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = "api",
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The YouTube Data API lets you incorporate functions normally executed on the YouTube website into your own website or application. The lists below identify the different types of resources that you can retrieve using the API. The API also supports methods to insert, update, or delete many of these resources.

This reference guide explains how to use the API to perform all of these operations. The guide is organized by resource type. A resource represents a type of item that comprises part of the YouTube experience, such as a video, a playlist, or a subscription. For each resource type, the guide lists one or more data representations, and resources are represented as JSON objects. The guide also lists one or more supported methods `(LIST, POST, DELETE, etc.)` for each resource type and explains how to use those methods in your application.

The following requirements apply to YouTube Data API requests:

- Every request must either specify an API key (with the key parameter) or provide an OAuth 2.0 token. 
  Your API key is available in the [Developer Console's](https://console.developers.google.com/) **API Access** pane for your project.
- You **must** send an authorization token for every insert, update, and delete request. You must also send an authorization token for any request that retrieves the authenticated user's private data.

In addition, some API methods for retrieving resources may support parameters that require authorization or may contain additional metadata when requests are authorized. For example, a request to retrieve a user's uploaded videos may also contain private videos if the request is authorized by that specific user.

- The API supports the OAuth 2.0 authentication protocol. You can provide an OAuth 2.0 token in either of the following ways:
- Use the `access_token` query parameter like this: ?`access_token=oauth2-token`
- Use the HTTP `Authorization` header like this: `Authorization: Bearer oauth2-token`
  Complete instructions for implementing OAuth 2.0 authentication in your application can be found in the [authentication guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to make a work around that situation by creating console application program that does the thing. 
Authentication mechanism moved into console application and passed the results to the service. In a service made a call into that application every n seconds. This solution worked like a charm. Ugly one, but it worked. Now i can give application access to profile data and use it where I want to.
If anyone will have a better solution I would be glad to read it.